# CSS rules gets applied after slight delay

Tags: html, css

I have the following embedded CSS code in head:

```
div {
    display: none;
}

div:nth-child(3),
div:target {
    display: inline-block;
}

div:target~div {
    display: none;
}
```

The HTML is structured such a way:

```
<body>
    <div id="a"></div>
    <div id="b"></div>
    <div id="c"></div>
</body>
```

Basically, in the absence of a valid fragment identifier, #c will show, otherwise the div with id that corresponds to the fragment identifier will show.

===

My problem is that, when I load something like "http://example.com#a" , there will be a flash of #c for like 20ms before #a gets displayed.

When I check the filmstrip, it was clear that the content was already styled, so how can it be that the rule "div:target" takes effect 20ms after "div:nth-child(3)"?

Granted, I only tested it in the latest Chrome so I don't know if it happens in other browsers.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior in any browser.

Comment: If your styles are embedded in the `<head>` and the HTML you provided is in the `<body>` then there should be no delay. If you have JavaScript that reads the hash and sets one of the `<div>` tags as the selected one then maybe that is delayed. But the CSS alone should not be delayed at all.

Comment: @Intervalia That's what I thought too. But its definitely happening and there's no javascript involved here. Maybe I'll try see if i can reproduce this on another page and then I'll post to code here.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so after what @Intervalia said, I went and check my JavaScript just to see if it made any difference even though nothing there was messing with hashes in there.

What I discovered was:

Having a script tag was the cause of this problem.
It didn't matter that there was no JS inside the script tag. I don't know how and why but just having `<script></script>` in the document body causes this.